# R: iterate over words in sentence, and give position of a certain word in sentence

Tags: r, loops, cpu-word

It works that it iterates over word, but the variable "word" contains a word, instead of the number (position) of that word in the row. For example, in the first row, 'yzi' has number 1, and 'runner' has number 3. Can anyone help?

Comment: where is your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
lapply(strsplit(output$text, ' '), function(x) seq_along(x)^2)

#[[1]]
# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100 121 144 169 196

#[[2]]
# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100 121 144 169 196

#[[3]]
# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100 121 144 169

#[[4]]
# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100

#...
#...
```

Or in a loop -

```
for(row in 1:nrow(output)){
  list=strsplit(output$text[row], " ")[[1]]
  for(i in seq_along(list)){
    print(i^2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really. I want it to return numbers per row, thus to include it in the iteration. For every row, it should return for every word a new number that comes out the formula..

Comment: Thus "word" in the code that I put in the question, needs to be a position number instead of an actual word. And it can then put the number in a formula for each word in one row, and then (maybe it's easiest) if it returns a sum of these numbers.

Comment: See the updated code with `for` loop. I changed `word` with `i` in the inner loop since now it is an index (number). Is that closer to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(strsplit(output$text, ' '), ~ seq_along(.x)^2)
```